# Custom ViewGroup incorrect onLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-custom-view, viewgroup

I'm trying to write my own layout class. But I'm having trouble with the onLayout. If I extend LinearLayout and have it do onLayout and I call super.onMeasure() in my onMeasure, everything works. But it's not working extending ViewGroup. What's showing is the first left most child gets rendered correctly but the rest don't show up or are not the right size.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;

class ManualPanel extends ViewGroup
{
    private int totalDivs;
    private int[] sizesArr;

    public ManualPanel(final Context context)
    {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public ManualPanel(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);

        final TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.ManualPanel);

        final String[] sizeStr = a.getString(R.styleable.ManualPanel_sizes).split("/");
        final String[] fracArr = sizeStr[0].split(",");
        a.recycle();

        int sum = 0;
        sizesArr = new int[fracArr.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < sizesArr.length; i++) {
            sizesArr[i] = Integer.valueOf(fracArr[i]);
            sum += sizesArr[i];
        }
        totalDivs = Math.max(sum, Integer.valueOf(sizeStr[1]));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(final int widthMeasureSpec, final int heightMeasureSpec)
    {
        final int children = getChildCount();
        final int totalWidth = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
        final int totalHeight = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);

        totalDivs = Math.max(totalDivs, children);

        final int[] arr = IntArray.copyOf(sizesArr, children);
        final int width[] = new int[children];
        int sum = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < children; i++) {
            width[i] = (arr[i] * totalWidth) / totalDivs;
            sum += width[i];
        }
        for (int i = 0, diff = totalWidth - sum; diff > 0; i = ++i % children) {
            width[i]++;
            diff--;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < children; i++) {
            final View view = getChildAt(i);
            final LayoutParams lp = view.getLayoutParams();

            lp.width = width[i];
            view.setLayoutParams(lp);
            view.measure(MeasureSpec.EXACTLY | lp.width, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY | totalHeight);
        //  view.measure(MeasureSpec.AT_MOST | lp.width, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST | totalHeight);
        }
        setMeasuredDimension(totalWidth, totalHeight);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b)
    {
        final int children = getChildCount(), height = getMeasuredHeight();
        for (int i = 0; i < children; i++) {
            final View view = getChildAt(i);

            if (view.getVisibility() != View.VISIBLE)
                continue;

            final int width = view.getMeasuredWidth();
            view.layout(l, 0, left + width, height);
            l += width;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A quick overview to help you understand properly overriding ViewGroup. in onMeasure() you measure the dimensions of the ViewGroup and its children. in onLayout() you position all the children and draw with measured dimensions. in dispatchDraw() you can override how the children are drawn if you want to do any effects etc. also I concur with Roman

Answer (score 1):

ViewGroup doesn't know how to place children. Or how to draw them. You have to do it youself.

Comment: well, I should be placing them in onLayout. Things are showing up, so it's drawing something, just not 100% correct. What do I need to add?

Comment: well, draw calls should not be placed in onLayout on onMeasure methods

Comment: You should write your own onDraw(). As for how to do it, import Android source code and take the text of the on... procedures from there, from existing Layouts, and change these procedures step by step, one after one. So, you could localize your errors.

Comment: And base at start not on LinearLayout analysis - it is too complex, but on FrameLayout.

Comment: onDraw() method mustn't draw child views. ViewGroup calls children drawing methods in its dispatchDraw(). What LinearLayout does int its onDraw() method is drawing dividers if necessary, it has nothing to do with children there except getting info about their size.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried your layout in action. But here is what I see.
Look at your line

```
view.layout(l, 0, left + width, height);
```

Your `left` variable seems to always be equal to zero, since you do not change it inside the loop.

Comment: Ok, I think that was it, except that I'm not setting the height correctly.